# How to install japanese font on centos 5.5

Tags: linux, centos

I'm Linux newbie.I would like to know "How to install Japanese font on centos 5.5". Please share me a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (as root, in the command line):

```
yum install fonts-japanese
```

Or this:

```
sudo yum install fonts-japanese
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither `sudo yum install fonts-japanese` nor `yum install fonts-japanese` are working. Depending upon which OS you were using. You can try this "`sudo yum search japan`". It will give you plenty of results. Depending upon what is required install one of those.

Comment: you are correct.  When I tried `sudo yum install fonts-japanese` i got result like, "no package fonts-japanese available".  I am yet to check `sudo yum search japan` command.  will update soon.